# Создание дополнительных каталогов в res

Tags: android, android-studio

Добрый день . Никак не найду ответа на вопрос "Можно ли создать дополнительные каталоги в res в Android Studio , у меня есть много XML хотелось бы все по своим папка раскидать но только как? Пробовал создавать папки в layout и в res , и ничего не получалось . Заранее спасибо !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22426467 или [вот подробнее](https://antonioleiva.com/android-multiple-resource-folders/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще, все разметки должны быть в папке `layout`, но если уж вы хотите разделить их, то создайте любую другую папку в каталоге `res`, например, `layout2`. Помещаете туда свои разметки и компилируете проект. Все идентификаторы ресурсов хранятся в `R.java`, зайдите в него и найдите блок `layout2` с вашими именами разметок. Далее зайдите в активность и поменяйте ошибочную строку на

```
setContentView(R.layout2.yourLayout);
```

Не знаю что на это скажет студия, попробуйте.

**EDIT**

Вы можете создавать папки в `layout` директории. Для этого создaйте, например, папкy `a`, далее в `build.gradle`

```
sourceSets {
main {
    res.srcDirs =
    [
            'src/main/res/layout/a',
            'src/main/res/layout',
            'src/main/res'
    ]
}
}
```

И писать надо вот так `R.layout.a.yourLayout`